# how to extract list of hrefs from javascript onclick attributes and to parse through looping in python using scrapy?

Tags: javascript, python-2.7, scrapy

```
<div id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_pnlPages" style="width: auto;">
<a id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_page1" class="aspNetDisabled" style="display:inline-block;font-weight:bold;height:22px;width:22px;background-image:url(../Images/count.png);">1</a><a id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_page2" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$page2','')" style="display:inline-block;height:22px;width:22px;background-image:url(../Images/count.png);">2</a><a id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_page3" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$page3','')" style="display:inline-block;height:22px;width:22px;background-image:url(../Images/count.png);">3</a><a id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_page4" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$page4','')" style="display:inline-block;height:22px;width:22px;background-image:url(../Images/count.png);">4</a><a id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_page5" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$page5','')" style="display:inline-block;height:22px;width:22px;background-image:url(../Images/count.png);">5</a>
 </div>
```

how to extract all list of hrefs from above javascript onclick attributes and to parse through looping in python scrapy?

Answer (score 0):

that will get you your hrefs as an array of strings.

`const hrefArray = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('a')).map(el => el.href);`

Comment: how to loop all list of hrefs ..in detail please? i tried this for const hrefArray in Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('a')).map(el => el.href): is it okay? it shows some syntax error!@Daniel Isaac Geslin

Comment: so this is the same thing but will older syntax:

`var hrefEls = document.querySelectorAll('a');`
`var hrefArray = [];`
`for (var i = 0; i < hrefEls.length; i++) hrefArray.push(hrefEls[i].href);`